# Android : IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "D1%" on Galaxy Tab3 Lite (goyawifi)

Tags: java, android, andengine

To day, in my Google Developer Console -> Crash & ARn, I receive a crash response below

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "D1%"
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at afa.a(SourceFile:102)
at aer.a(SourceFile:174)
at aer.a(SourceFile:151)
at afw.run(SourceFile:14)
at afy.run(SourceFile:30)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

on Galaxy Tab3 Lite (goyawifi) - Android 4.2

I'm using andengine to develop game, please show me how to fix it.

Comment: You are trying to cast "D1%" as an integer at some point. 


Make sure you have an Integer instead of "D1%" where you are trying to do the cast.

Comment: I know it, but I cant try / catch because it's at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1429), It seem android os code and I cant modify.

Comment: Is there not anything more in the error log?

Comment: Maybe debug the code step by step and see which line of code is causing the exception?

Even if the Exception is seen in the android.os.Parcel, your code / variable is going through it.